# How to create a more natural jump with ease in and ease out?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm designing a game where the 'player' has to jump. I have a working jump function, but the jump is very 'linear'. I want the jump to have 'ease in' and 'ease out'.

This means that the first part of the jump should go up faster, while it decreases in speed near the 'top' and should increase in speed while it moves down.

I've tried a few things with:

```
var jumpStartTime: CGFloat = 0.0
var jumpCurrentTime: CGFloat = 0.0

var currentDuration = CGFloat(currentTime) - jumpStartTime
```

However, I don't know where and how to start.

This is the functions I have for the linear jump.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if onGround && !gameOver {
        if self.initialJumpY == nil {
            self.initialJumpY = self.character.position.y
        }

        if self.character.position.y - self.initialJumpY! < 100 {
            self.character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 75))
        } else {
            self.character.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0.0
        }
    }

     self.onGround = false

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.character.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = 0.0
    self.initialJumpY = nil
}
```

**How can I make a more 'natural', linear jump?**

Thanks, guys!

Nick.

Comment: Use a ballistic curve?

Comment: why not use gravity on the character?

Comment: @rakeshbs I do: `physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -2.5)`, but that still makes it 'linear', or this there another way of applying gravity?

Answer (score 2):

First of all a 'linear' jump will never be natural.
You need to apply a negative acceleration to the velocity. The change of the velocity would be linear.
the velocity formula would look like this:
v = v0 - factor * t.

t being the time v0 would be the initial velocity and the factor being something that you try out for a nice effect.
With velocity in meters per second and time in seconds the factor on Earth would be 9.81 for the gravity of earth.

Comment: Alright, but how about the jump itself? That shouldn't be negative in the beginning?

Comment: @NGAFD - sorry i did't get you were already using a physics engine. Maybe your gravity is just not strong enough so it doesn't affect the body as strongly as you expect. also there appears to be a property "affectedByGravity" that needs to be set on the physics body.

Comment: I've increased gravity and the jumping velocity, which causes a more natural look, so that's great. It's not as good as I want it but it is a start, so thanks for that!